# How to get TLS Cert in Unbound

Tags: dns

I wanna connect to my DNS over TLS server (blahdns.com) 
It works great with stubby client, but I wanna try on Unbound (Ubuntu 18.04) 
I saw some posts said I have to config with TLS, How can I get those cert.pem

```
tls-cert-bundle: "/etc/ssl/cert.pem"
forward-zone:
    name: "."
    forward-tls-upstream: yes
    forward-addr: 108.61.201.119@853
```

Answer (score 1):

The `tls-cert-bundle` location will vary depending on the flavor of linux.  This is not the complete `unbound.conf` but has the relevant portions for DNS over TLS using cloudflare

```
server:
  tls-cert-bundle: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

forward-zone:
  name: "."
  forward-tls-upstream: yes
  forward-addr: 1.1.1.1@853#cloudflare-dns.com
  forward-addr: 1.0.0.1@853#cloudflare-dns.com
  forward-addr: 2606:4700:4700::1111@853#cloudflare-dns.com
  forward-addr: 2606:4700:4700::1001@853#cloudflare-dns.com
```